# Convert array of objects to array of strings

Tags: javascript

```
[
  { "text": "demo1" },
  { "text": "demo2" }
]
```

to

```
["demo1", "demo2"]
```

I have tried using reduce()

Comment: you can also use `underscore.js`'s [pluck function](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck). it's as easy as `_.pluck(demoArray, 'text');`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for that:

```js
var arr = [
  {"text":"demo1"},
  {"text":"demo2"}
];
var texts = arr.map(function(el) {
  return el.text;
});
console.log(texts);
```

And with ES6, you can use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
var texts = arr.map((el) => el.text);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map()` for this:

```
var myArray = [ {"text": "demo1"}, {"text": "demo2"} ];
var newArray = myArray.map( el => el.text); // [ "demo1", "demo2"]
```

Basically `map()` performs an operation on every element of an array returning a new array.

It's hard to do this with `reduce()` when you have such a small array, but still possible:

```
var myArray = [ {"text": "demo1"}, {"text": "demo2"} ];
var newArray = myArray.reduce( (a,b) => [a.text, b.text]) // [ "demo1", "demo2" ]
```

In this example `a` is the first item and `b` is the second item.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var values = [
{"text":"demo1"},
{"text":"demo2"}
];
var log = [];
angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
  this.push(value.text);
}, log);
alert(log);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using underscore js it will be more easy to convert an array using pluck and more efficient then reduce .

```
var arr = [  {"text":"demo1"},  {"text":"demo2"}];    
_.pluck(arr , 'text');

output:-
=> ["demo1", "demo2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` to get `text` from the array , Then use  [**join**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to get the string

```
var a =[
{"text":"demo1"},
{"text":"demo2"}
]
var sArray = [];
a.forEach(function(item){
sArray.push(item.text)
})

var myString  = sArray.join(',');
console.log(myString)
```

Alternatively you can also create a variable & `concat` each `item.text`

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/f9djbcbg/3/)