# Loop through 2 arrays to find index of where object keys match and then delete that object

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, splice

I have these two arrays :

```
array1 = [{firstname: 'abc', age: 24}];

array2 = [{name: 'bcg', age: 33}, {name:'abc', age: 55}];
```

I want to loop through both arrays and remove the object from the second array (`array 2`) that has a the same name key value as the first object in array 1. So essentially loop through both arrays to see where key values match and then remove the relevant object `array2[1]` from the second array.

I tried doing this but it did not work:

```
for (let p = 0; p < array1.length; p++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    if (array1[p].firstname === array2[i].name) {
      array2.splice(i,1);
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way this can work with JavaScript ?

Comment: How many objects will the first array contain?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter array of objects with another array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005396/filter-array-of-objects-with-another-array-of-objects)

Comment: also: [Filter array of objects based on another array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894352/filter-array-of-objects-based-on-another-array-in-javascript) combined with [Convert array of objects to array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913343/convert-array-of-objects-to-array-of-strings)

Answer (score 4):

You can simply achieve it by just using [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along with [Set.has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const array1 = [{firstname: 'abc', age: 24}];

const array2 = [{name: 'bcg', age: 33}, {name:'abc', age: 55}];

const namesArr = new Set(array1.map(obj => obj.firstname));

const res = array2.filter(({ name }) => !namesArr.has(name));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @pilchard Thanks again! I updated code snippet and it's a learning for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in conjunction with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
const array1 = [{firstname: 'abc', age: 24}], array2 = [{name: 'bcg', age: 33}, {name:'abc', age: 55}];
let res = array2.filter(x => !array1.some(y => y.firstname === x.name));
console.log(res);
```

For increased performance with a larger amount of data, you can construct a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to store all the names in the first array and lookup each name in constant time.

```js
const array1 = [{firstname: 'abc', age: 24}], array2 = [{name: 'bcg', age: 33}, {name:'abc', age: 55}];
let names1 = new Set(array1.map(x => x.firstname));
let res = array2.filter(x => !names1.has(x.name));
console.log(res);
```